# Use environment variable for a gem (pHash)

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, phash

I'm on OSX and I've installed [the pHash gem](https://github.com/toy/pHash).

When using the gem, I have the following error: `Could not open library 'libpHash.dylib'`.

In the docs, the author says

> You can specify path to pHash library explicitly using environment variable like `PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib`.

The problem is that I don't know how to actually call this environment variable in the context of my ruby program. The gem is called with `require 'phash'`, but where can I  specify the ENV variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your ruby program like this:

```
PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib ruby path/to/your/program.rb
```

alternatively, export the environment variable like this:

```
export PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib
```

and then you should be able to run your ruby program normally.